# python to calculate the exact number of distribution in some column is Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

write a python program to obtain a dataframe(pandas)-"pre_data_matrix" , and in this dataframe there is a column named "PostTextPolarity", its value is between -1 and 1, want to calculate the numbers of "PostTextPolarity" when it is >0,<0 and =0, for example , there are total more than 30000 items, maybe the number of "PostTextPolarity" when it is >0 is 10000,and maybe maybe the number of "PostTextPolarity" when it is < 0 is 20000, I want to obtain the exact number, the program is:

```
    select_sql = "select userID,userName,userURL,postTime,postText,postTextLength,likesCount,sharesCount,commentsCount,postTextPolarity,postTextSubjectivity from fb_pre_davi_group_members_posts"
    cur.execute(select_sql)

    pre_data = cur.fetchall()
    pre_data_list = list(pre_data )
    ...
    pre_data_matrix = pd.DataFrame(pre_data_list,columns = ['userId','UserName','UserURL','PostTime','PostText','PostTextLength','LikesCount','SharesCount','CommentsCount','PostTextPolarity','PostTextSubjectivity'])
    print(pre_data_matrix )
```

and it shows:

```
         LikesCount  SharesCount  CommentsCount      PostTextPolarity  \
    0       0            0              0                   0.0   
    1       0            0              0    0.3571428571428571   
    2       3            0              0                   1.0   
    3      11            0              0                   0.0   
    4      11            0              0   0.46909090909090906   
    5       0            0              0                   0.9   
    6      11            0              1                 0.625   
    7      11            0              1                   0.0   
    8      11            0              0               0.56875   
    9      11            0              0                   0.0   
   10      0            0              1   0.08333333333333333   
   11      20            0              2                   0.0   
   12      4            0              1                   0.0   
   13      7            0              1                   0.0   
   14      11            0              1                  0.25   
   ...
```

could you please tell me how to obtain the exact number of PostTextPolarity  >0,=0, and <0,maybe need to use other library such as numpy

Comment: Take some time to watch this talk and practice the concepts/examples.  Your solution should become evident - http://pandas.pydata.org/talks.html#pycon-us-2015

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Use np.where via the pandas library:

```
g = pd.np.where(df.PostTextPolarity == 0,'Equals 0',pd.np.where(df.PostTextPolarity < 0,'< 0','> 0'))

df.groupby(g)['PostTextPolarity'].count().rename_axis('Category').reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   Category  PostTextPolarity
0       > 0                 8
1  Equals 0                 7
```